How to search different texts in multiple fields in Azure AI/Cognitive Search (Azure.search.documents)?
So, I want to have fields A, B, and C be searchable so that if I look search up some string "potato", it will look for that word in fields A, B, and C.
To do that, I created an index in Azure Search where A, B, and C are retrievable and searchable. This part works as expected.
What if I wanted to add in field D as well, but I want to it to be searched/filtered separately from ABC? Like if I am looking for (don't mind the syntax) ABC = "potato" AND D = "brand 1" , do I have to create a whole new index for just searching D?
What I have right now is one index with A, B, and C marked as searchable, and D is marked as filterable.
In the java code, I have a searchClient that uses that index.
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
    .setSearchFields(
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    );
SearchPagedIterable searchResults = searchClient.search("potato", searchOptions, Context.NONE);

I'm not sure how to add field D into the above code because I don't want to search field D for "potato" nor fields ABC for "brand 1".
If I need to create an index per separate searchable field, that is doable. My only problem is that I have a lot of fields. If I needed to have an index to search them all, that is a lot of indexes and java code.
Ideally, there is a way through SearchOptions or SearchClient that I am able to separate searches so I can do something like "potato" AND D = "brand 1"
I also see this question which is very similar but with no answers: Azure Cognitive Search multiple fields with different text

Can you try something like the following (untested code):
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions()
    .setSearchFields(
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    )
    .setFilter("D eq 'brand 1'")
SearchPagedIterable searchResults = searchClient.search("potato", searchOptions, Context.NONE);

What this code should do is do a search for potato in fields A, B, C and do a OData filter query on field D.

Thanks, this works for adding a filter. If I had to add another separate search field, would I then have to create another searchOptions and another index? I think using another setSearchFields in the same one will override the last one.

Not sure I understand your comment. Can you please elaborate?

So I want to search ABC for "X" and D for "Y" using the Lucene analyzer.
.setFilter() works for filters but not for full-text search. Is there a way to full-text search for different values for separate fields, or does it only work for filtering like in your answer above?

AFAIK, For full text for different values for separate field, you will need to perform multiple searches (one search for searching "X" in ABC and another search for searching "Y" in D) and then combine the results somehow.
